# PostgreSQL password not expiring?

Tags: postgresql

I have run the following query on a PostgreSQL user:

```
ALTER ROLE testuser VALID UNTIL '2020/01/01';
```

To temporarily prevent the user from logging in.

If I run the query:

```
SELECT usename, valuntil FROM pg_user;
```

I receive:

```
+----------+------------------------+
| usename  | valuntil               |
+----------+------------------------+
| testuser | 2020-01-01 00:00:00-04 |
+----------+------------------------+
```

But I can still login with this user without any issue. I would expect that if I attempt to login with this user, that the login should fail and I would receive an error that the password is expired (or something similar).

Am I understanding waht the 'VALID UNTIL' statement does?

Comment: Maybe the user is set to `trust` in pg_hba.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The VALID UNTIL clause defines an expiration time for a password only, 
not for the role per se. In particular, the expiration time is 
not enforced when logging in using a non-password-based authentication method.
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html)

Comment: The user was created with 'create user testuser with encrypted password 'testpassword'; which I believe would be setup as password-based authentication?

Comment: As 'horse...' said. If they are set up as trust in the hba file they will not be prompted and thus be non-password based authentication

Comment: That was it. They were setup as 'trust' in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Saw something in the docs, and seemed very straight forward for me (correct me if im wrong), but i think it's because the user still have *LOGIN* rights.

```
'ALTER ROLE testuser [LOGIN|NOLOGIN]'
```

Comment: That is somewhat incorrect. ```LOGIN``` just says that ```ROLE``` can connect to a database by any of the auth methods available. ```VALID UNTIL``` just covers password connection methods e.g md5 and scram. So it comes down to what you are trying to achieve, denying all connections by a user or enforcing password expiration for password authentication.